# canvas.toDataURL("image/png") throws security error exception WORDPRESS

Tags: php

I am using Wordpress and project root directory is `undersubdirectory`, i.e `http:localhost/prjctroot/project`.

```
var oCanvas     =   document.getElementById("image1");
var canvasData  =   oCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Getting this error in Firebug:

```
Security error
var canvasData  =   oCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Same code works on other test file (not using any CMS just a simple file code for test).

I think some thing is wrong with Wordpress.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the URL of the image and the URL of the page where this is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your image source domain. It must match the document domain to get image data like that.

See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements

Comment: @moeenakhtar if the answer helped you, please consider clicking the green checkmark next to it to mark it as the solution to your problem.